Module over associated graded of a filtered ring
Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring equipped with am exhaustive filtration
$F_\bullet R$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated left $R$-module. Let $F_\bullet M$ be an exhaustive filtration of $M$ that is compatible with $F_\bullet R$. Form the associated graded as usual
$$\operatorname{gr}^F R = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} F_i R / F_{i-1} R$$
$$\operatorname{gr}^F M = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} F_i M / F_{i-1} M$$
(where the $(-1)$-th piece of each filtration is $0$ by definition). Then $\operatorname{gr}^F M$ is a $(\operatorname{gr}^F R)$-module, with scalar multiplication on homogeneous pieces defined by
$$(r_i + F_{i-1} R) (x_j + F_{j-1} M) = (r_i x_j + F_{i+j-1} M)$$
Suppose the filtration $F_\bullet M$ is good, i.e., $\operatorname{gr}^F M$ is a finitely generated $(\operatorname{gr}^F R)$-module. Is it true that $M$ has a natural structure of $\operatorname{gr}^F R$-module?
At the bottom of page 26 of this note, the author has assumed this to be the case (for the localization $M_P$ to make sense) without saying anything about it, but I just can't figure out how one is supposed to define the scalar multiplication.

Isn‘t $S_0$ a subring of $R$ and thus $M$ a module over $S_0$? Then $M$ is an $S$-module by zero action on the nonzero graded pieces.

From reading the note briefly, my understanding is that it should say $S_P \otimes_{S} \mathrm{gr}^F M$.
